# How to make a subfunction in Google Script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets

## Hello

I am currently making a library and trying to figure out how to make a function accessible from another similar to `myLibrary.function().subFunction();`

I have tried a few different techniques to achieve this but none seem to work correctly.

I am used to the typical library setup such as `MyLibrary.function();`  But I can't seem to figure out how to extend it to `myLibrary.function.subFunction();`

#### Any help is appreciated greatly, thanks.

So far I have tried this:

```js
function myFunction() {

logger.log('hello');

}

function myFunction.subFunction() {

logger.log('world');

}
```

So far I get an error when running this.  I expect that if I write `myLibrary.myFunction.subFunction();` in my paired Google Script that I will get something similar to `hello world` written in the log.

Comment: Look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 0):

try to use the information I found here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/custom-functions?hl=en

maybe it'll help you :)

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I was looking for a nested function.  This helped out a lot.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).